# Mongoose aggregating the documents, based on the time difference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a schema with following fields

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
  roomId: { type: String, required: true, ref: 'Room' },
  timestamp: Date,
  currentTemp: Number,
  outsideTemp: Number,
  desiredTemp: Number
});
```

Now I want to aggregate the documents in this collection and return the response like

```
{
    timestamp: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10..,24],
    currentTemp: [34,45,.....],
    outsideTemp: [14,45,.....],
    desiredTemp: [34,45,.....]
}
```

I have some match condition and I am able to select the documents based on the match condition. Now I want to aggregate the selected documents and produce a result like above.

The timestamp value is bound by a lower bound and upper bound. The upper bound and lower bound is passed from the client and the aggregation should be based on the difference between the lower and upper. If the difference is

```
- 1 day : group by hour

- 3 days : group by 6 hrs

- 7 days : group by 12 hours

- < 30 days : group by day

- > 30 days : group by week
```

currentTemp is the average of all the documents currentTemp property in that time period. Similarly for outsideTemp and desiredTemp.

How can I do this ?

EDIT:

Sample data set

```
{
            "_id": "5656bfd94d6f6304ff140000",
            "roomId": "5656bc124d6f6335051b0000",
            "timestamp": "2015-11-15T08:59:20Z",
            "currentTemp": 10.55,
            "outsideTemp": 43.83,
            "desiredTemp": 21.32
        }, {
            "_id": "5656bfd94d6f6304ff150000",
            "roomId": "5656bc124d6f633505200000",
            "timestamp": "2015-06-01T06:33:49Z",
            "currentTemp": 32.47,
            "outsideTemp": 49.65,
            "desiredTemp": 20.99
        }, {
            "_id": "5656bfd94d6f6304ff160000",
            "roomId": "5656bc124d6f633505250000",
            "timestamp": "2014-12-31T23:47:54Z",
            "currentTemp": 35.69,
            "outsideTemp": 29.91,
            "desiredTemp": 20.15
        }, {
            "_id": "5656bfd94d6f6304ff170000",
            "roomId": "5656bc124d6f6335051e0000",
            "year": 2015,
            "month": 3,
            "day": 12,
            "hour": 21,
            "minute": 13,
            "second": 38,
            "inDST": true,
            "timestamp": "2015-11-14T07:56:42Z",
            "currentTemp": 27.65,
            "outsideTemp": 41.4,
            "desiredTemp": 24.68
        }
```

Comment: Would have been really helpful if you could edit your question to include some sample data set and the expected output from that sample.

Comment: @chridam I added the sample dataset. I want to average currentTemp, outsideTemp, and desiredTemp in a time period and group by hour, 6 hour, 12 hour etc

Comment: Thanks for the update. How do we go about validating this sample data set? You forgot another crucial part, your expected output from that sample, can you include that as well?

Comment: @chridam the expected output is defined in the question. It should be three arrays with timestamp, currentTemp, outsideTemp and desiredTemp. Check question